# Consistent spark cluster on eks

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I used spark-submit as described in the spark [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html).

But I was looking for something else for my deployment. I want a cluster that is always on. Meaning that the master and the workers are always up. I want to connect to the spark master from inside a python script with the masters' IP.

What is the best way to achieve this with EKS ? Is the [spark operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) a good option ?

EDIT: using PySpark

Comment: What is the use case to connect to master? Is it for sparkSession or something else?

Comment: for a sparkSession + i'm using pyspark